# How do I prevent <%@page... %> attribute from adding a <BR/>

Tags: java, jsp

My JSP looks similar to the following...

```
<%@page import "java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import "java.util.List%>
<%@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
   ...
%>
```

Each <%%> is resulting in an extra new line... how can I prevent this from happening without having to glue all of the %><% together? This is resulting in 3+ new lines (pretty much one per import).  If I blend all the imports together, it is still leaving at least one new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using JSP 2.1 or higher you can use:

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

For older versions, and if you are using tomcat(!),  you can use:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>trimSpaces</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

in your web.xml.

Answer (score 2):

You can "glue" the `%><%` together, but have new lines inside a single directive:

```
<%@page import "java.util.ArrayList"
%><%@page import "java.util.List"
%><%@page contentType="application/json" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```